# Xcode Server - Run Integration on Pull Request

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration, xcode-server, xcode-bots, xcode-server-bots

I am setting up CI on Xcode Server and I am trying to start integration as soon as Pull requests are created. My repository is on GitHub. Is there any way it can be done. I didn’t find any option in Xcode Server. Only thing I have found is to change repository.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!!!

Comment: You could take a look at https://fastlane.tools/

Comment: also apple has a description on there website https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/PublishYourCodetoaSourceRepository.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013292-CH8-SW1